# How to add multiselect UITableView value to UITextField in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem to add multi select table value to text field.
My code is like this
In DidSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 txtactivity.text=[activityarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        lblactivity.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[idActivityarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        txtactivity.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[activityarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [[tableactivity cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
}
```

I am getting output like this

[image]

CellForRowAtIndexPath

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell  *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[activityarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

My problem is I am getting only one value in the text box. I need to get all the selected values in the text box. How to do this? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: append selected row string value to the text field instead of assigning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a NSMutableArray and initalize it at `viewDidLoad`. Then use the following code.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   if(!arrSelectedValue containsObject:[activityarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]){
     [arrSelectedValue addObject:[activityarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
     txtactivity.text = [arrSelectedValue componentsJoinedByString:@","];
   }

   [[tableactivity cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   if(arrSelectedValue containsObject:[activityarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]){
     [arrSelectedValue removeObject:[activityarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
     txtactivity.text = [arrSelectedValue componentsJoinedByString:@","];
   }

   [[tableactivity cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
}
```

Comment: @Muju : Actually this has nothing to do with scrolling. I think may be you are not using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` which leads to reallocating cell every time and the laggy scrolling.

Comment: I am using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier in cellforrowatindexpath

Comment: Can you show me `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method's code?

Comment: The code looks right. What problem are you getting while scrolling?

Comment: When I scroll below cell also get selected

Comment: Ok. Do one thing write this code inside cellForRowAtIndex before `return cell` -  `if(arrSelectedValue containsObject:[activityarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]){[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];}else{ [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];}`

Comment: Can you Please answer my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43539307/how-to-post-string-with-special-character-and-thai-language-using-xml-parsing-in

Answer (score 2):

try this one, without storing into array directly you can append the string as per your selection. I hope this will work for you.

```
[txtactivity setText:[[txtactivity text] stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@", %@", [activityarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope txtactivity is your textfield. In your code, you are just setting the textfield text as the selected value.It will replace the current text. Instead of that append the selected value with the textfield content. 
Change the code

```
txtactivity.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[activityarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

to this

```
txtactivity.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@",txtactivity.text,[activityarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]
```

This will append the newly selected value to the content of textfield.

Comment: if I select 3 value then it overrite.

Comment: It won't over write anything unless You are setting text (txtactivity.text = codes.. ) some where else. You need to remove all othet txtactivit.text codes.  Also in addition to my point, if you need to handle de-selcting row, I would suggest to go for the solution suggested by "Poles" :)